# How can I display an array of arrays in a ListView (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, arrays, json, xamarin

I want to read an array of arrays from api, and make a ListView resource for each array inside de main array in Xamarin Forms.

I actually make the class model for the api resource, I tried to make a foreach element of my rootobject, and put them into a Observable Collection and set that as a ItemSource of my listview.

**this is my xaml**

```
<StackLayout>
     <!--ListView de Clientes-->
     <ListView x:Name="ListClientes">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding cliente}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <!--ListView de Proveedores-->
       <ListView x:Name="ListProveedores">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding proveedor}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <!--ListView de Trasnportistas-->
       <ListView x:Name="ListTransportistas">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding transportista}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

**this is my class model for the api resource**

```
public class ArrImportExport
    {
        [JsonProperty("id_import_export")]
        public string id_import_export { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("cliente")]
        public string cliente { get; set; }
    }

    public class ArrProveedore
    {
        [JsonProperty("id_proveedor")]
        public string id_proveedor { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("proveedor")]
        public string proveedor { get; set; }
    }

    public class ArrTransport
    {
        [JsonProperty("id_transportistas")]
        public string id_transportista { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("transportista")]
        public string transportista { get; set; }
    }

    public class ArrMultiple
    {
        [JsonProperty("arr_import_export")]
        public List<ArrImportExport> arr_import_export { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("arr_proveedores")]
        public List<ArrProveedore> arr_proveedores { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("arr_transportistas")]
        public List<ArrTransport> arr_transport { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("arr_multiple")]
        public List<ArrMultiple> arr_multiple { get; set; }
    }
```

**this is how a handle it in my main class**

```
var resultado = await cliente.GetAsync(url);
var json = resultado.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


RootObject tr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

                foreach (ArrMultiple arr in tr.arr_multiple) {
                    //await DisplayAlert("Array", arr.arr_import_export.ToString(), "Ok");

                    var arrClientes = new ObservableCollection<ArrImportExport>(arr.arr_import_export);
                    ListClientes.ItemsSource = arrClientes;

                    var arrProvedores = new ObservableCollection<ArrProveedore>(arr.arr_proveedores);
                    ListProveedores.ItemsSource = arrProvedores;

                    var arrTransportistas = new ObservableCollection<ArrTransport>(arr.arr_transport);
                    ListTransportistas.ItemsSource = arrTransportistas;
                }
```

I expect to see all my clients in one listview, all my suppliers in other listview, and carriers too. but I only see clients and get an exception error:

```
value cannot be null. parameter name: list
```

Comment: the exception stack trace should show you which line causes the exception, or you should be able to identify it using the debugger.

Comment: how can I implement correctly the Stack trace?

Comment: it's a property of the Exception object

Comment: also, you're assigning ItemsSource for your ListViews in a loop, which means that each iteration of the loop will overwrite the previous ItemsSource.  You probably need to re-think this design.

Comment: @gabecm Hi , it seems like [Grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping) in listview. Often, large sets of data can become unwieldy when presented in a continuously scrolling list. Enabling grouping can improve the user experience in these cases by better organizing the content and activating platform-specific controls that make navigating data easier.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT hi, actually my problem isn't with design, what I'm trying to resolv is to read an a json object that contains a arrays, that also those arrays have their own arrays, for example, I have my principal object named "arr_multiple" it containes 3 arrays("arr_clientes", "arr_proveedores", "arr_transport"), they also contains their data.

Comment: @gabecm Okey , do you have a look at Grouping in listview ? This may fit your wants.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` in Xamarin.Forms is expected to have no other controls in its part of the layout (like in the StackLayout, in some Grid layouts it may work).

Possibly you could try to place this in the Grid with same row heights, it should work.

Comment: this isn't true.  You can have ListView on a page with other controls.  Multiple LIstViews on a page are not a great idea, but there is no rule that says a ListView has to be full page

Comment: @Jason it can work in some cases so full page was not the best wording, but you can't have stacklayout with ListView and something below it, not even another ListView required to see the problem.

Comment: Hi guys, that resolves the UI design, and I'll take this for it, but my problem is to get the data from the json, I don't know how to deserialize my json.

Comment: you should post another question that specifically focuses on the deserialization issue

Comment: @Jason, you're right, I must be more specific next time, and about your answer, Listview works good in stacklayout, i fix my problem and I see my 3 list in a stacklayout.